# How to disable, enable, then disable again scrolling in ipad/iphone with e.preventDefault();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I have it disabled already, and I can enable it again.
I used:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
}
```

In the document.ready(); to disable it.

And I used this to enable it.

```
function doTouchMove(state) {
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){
      return state;
    }
}
```

I have it so when a user double clicks on an element, the doTouchMove is called. But how do I make it disabled again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could create a toggle instead, where your *doTouchMove()* function switches between *false* and *true* every time it's called:

```
(function () { // Set up a closure so we don't pollute the global scope
    var state = false;
    function doTouchMove() {
        state = !state;
    }
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){
        return state;
    }
    document.getElementById("myDoubleClickElement").ondblclick = doTouchMove;
})();
```

Now, every time you double-click *#myDoubleClickElement*, it will toggle the *state* variable's value between *false* and *true*, effectively disabling on the even clicks and enabling on the odd clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Im the same user who asked this question... but I cleared my history & everything so I can't pick an answer or anything!

But what I did to fix it was put this

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
}
```

Into its own function, just as the doTouchMove() was. Then when I wanted it to stop moving again i would just call the name of that preventDefault function.

I don't know why it makes a difference but it works! :)